# Android: Toast and Edit.GetText

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I'm trying to find out if the user put something in the edit text.
It works but when I don't enter anything it wont show; "Please enter your name". 
Also tried null instead of "" or " " didn't work.

Any help?

```
    package com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class main extends Activity {

    EditText etName;
    Button btMake;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        btMake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPress);
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        btMake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(etName.getText().toString() == " "){

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter your name", duration);
                    toast.show();
                }else{
                    String Henk = etName.getText().toString();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome, " +  Henk, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I got it wrong but why do you suppose the default input is a `" "`

try this instead `if(etName.getText().equals(""))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: etName.getText().toString().equals("")

In java, when you compare String values, you need to use .equals(..) method. When you compare references for two objects then only ==

Answer (score 0):

Lars, instead of:

```
etName.getText().toString() == " ";
```

Use:

```
etName.getText().toString().length() == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
etName.getText().toString() == " "
```

That code will not work.  The " " actually creates a new String and compares memory addresses.  Well the memory address will not be the same because it is a different object.  Use

`etName.getText().toString().equals("")`